# How do you convert img.onload into a Promise.All?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

How do I get my `Promise.all(promiseArray).then()` then to trigger the callback?

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/white-sea-wxkdh

```
import "./styles.scss";
import o from "./letters/0.svg";
import i from "./letters/1.svg";
import a from "./letters/4.svg";
import d from "./letters/d.svg";
import g from "./letters/g.svg";
import m from "./letters/m.svg";
import h from "./letters/h.svg";
import r from "./letters/r.svg";
import n from "./letters/n.svg";
import w from "./letters/w.svg";

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const arena = 500;
const padding = 60;
const edge = arena - padding;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = "3";
ctx.strokeStyle = "DeepSkyBlue";
const origin = [padding, padding];
ctx.moveTo(...origin);
ctx.lineTo(edge, padding);
ctx.lineTo(edge, edge);
ctx.lineTo(padding, edge);
ctx.lineTo(...origin);
ctx.stroke();
let data = [g, o, o, d, null, m, o, r, n, i, n, g, null, h, a, r, w, o, o, d];
var imgEls = [];
var promiseArray = data.map((item, i) => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    let offset = i * 20;
    let img = new Image();
    let svg = new Blob([item], { type: "image/svg+xml" });
    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(svg);
    img.onload = () => {
      imgEls.push(img);
      ctx.drawImage(img, padding + offset, padding - 19);
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      console.log("loaded");
      res(img);
    };
    img.src = url;
  });
});

Promise.all(promiseArray).then(() => console.log(imgEls));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `data` array contains `null`s, `new Blob([null], { type: "image/svg+xml" });` results in the image failing - and you currently don't have error listeners.

When there's an error, either reject (or resolve, but don't push to the array of images):

```
img.onerror = res;
```

You could also consider not trying to create images of `null` in the first place - just skip those iterations:

```
var promiseArray = data.map((item, i) => {
  if (!item) {
    return;
  }
  return new Promise(...
    // rest of the code
```

(an `undefined` value in the array `Promise.all` is called with won't have any negative effect, don't worry)